# Getting the LABEL_DETECTION results from Google Vision API in another language

Tags: google-translate, google-cloud-vision

More specifically I would like to get the labels in french, so instead of:

```
  "labelAnnotations": [
    {
      "mid": "/m/019sc",
      "description": "black",
      "score": 0.95744693
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/07s6nbt",
      "description": "text",
      "score": 0.9175479
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/01zbnw",
      "description": "screenshot",
      "score": 0.8477094
    }]
```

I would like to get:

```
  "labelAnnotations": [
    {
      "mid": "/m/019sc",
      "description": "noir",
      "score": 0.95744693
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/07s6nbt",
      "description": "texte",
      "score": 0.9175479
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/01zbnw",
      "description": "capture d'écran",
      "score": 0.8477094
    }]
```

Or is Google Translate API my only solution currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Vision API **LABEL_DETECTION** are returned in English only. The [**Cloud Translate API**](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) can translate English labels into any of a number of [**other languages**](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages).

> **Reference** [Detect Labels](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels)